# RetinaPad equivalent for MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there anything like [RetinaPad](http://www.macstories.net/ipad/retinapad-enables-retina-graphics-for-iphone-apps-in-2x-mode/) for the MacBook Pro Retina?

Essentially, it would be something that would automate [the process of setting `NSHighResolutionCapable` to `true`](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120731145025768) so that text would render properly, even if all the graphics aren't updated yet.

If this doesn't exist, would it be something that could be [accomplished using `SIMBL`](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [Retinizer](http://retinizer.mikelpr.com/) might be what you're looking for. It's reversible, works on a per app/per user basis, and doesn't require you to edit the `Info.plist` files directly. I don't have an MBP, so I can't test it myself, but the pictures look pretty :)